# Appropriate type for storing numerical data and be able to interpolate

Tags: c#, data-structures, types, interpolation

I'm reading pairs of data (`xValues`, `yValues`) and I was wondering what is the best way of storing them. At this moment I am doing it in `List<double>,` `ObservableCollection` is not required because the data will remain constant in the program runtime. But I need to be able to do some operations with several (two) data sources. As the `xValues` between that two sources may not be the same, I need linear interpolation for that.

I've read things like `Dictionary`, `LinkedList`, etc, and I'm confused about what I need, and what could fits better for the little project.

When I've started to make the method that fills the missing data points I've encountered several difficulties:

I need to check for each point in series1 if the `xValue` is the same that in series2, but as the xValues are ordered I think it will be very performance damaging to check EVERY value in the whole list just to say, nope, there is not that `xValue`, let's interpolate and insert that new point.

How could I insert a point exactly between two not given the index but the values (x2>x1).

I think this is a common question when you work with 2D data points in programming, do you know if there is something implemented in C# or is there a code around to get me inspired?

Comment: Do you know if the same xValue will occur more than once? If not, I think a Dictionary might be the fastest for lookups.

Comment: No, I don't expect vertical lines or more than one yValue per xValue. Thanks.

Comment: To interpolate, you need to look at 2 points, 1 smaller, and 1 larger. This implies that you will not know the values you are looking for, so a Dictionary on second thought wont help. You will need a List/SortedList of some sort, Possibly Tuple<xValue, yValue>. If the list is sorted, you could use Linq to find the MAX value smaller than your point, and them assume the MIN value greater as the next point.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use sorted lists of X-Y pairs (`List<Tuple<double,double>>` would be an appropriate type for this). Let's assume you have two input lists, series1 and series2, which are sorted by X value, and you're checking series2 (and possibly interpolating) for the X values present in series1 (just as you state in the question). Because you need to check every coordinate in series1, there's a minimum complexity of O(n).

The key to keeping this efficient is the fact that the lists are ordered, which means you don't have to search the entire series2 list for each X value in series1. You do this by keeping a pointer to the current item in series2, and moving it as you traverse series1. Here's pseudo-C# to show what I mean.

```
var s2idx = 0;
foreach(s1 in series1)
{
    // go forward through series2 until you find the next interp target
    while(series2[s2dix].Item1 < s1.Item1 && s2idx < series2.Length)
        s2idx++;
    if(s2idx == series2.Length)
        // all s1 Xs are > the biggest s2 X, so just add the rest of the s1 points to your output 
        // or whatever else you want to do, then quit the foreach loop
    var s2 = series2[s2idx];
    if(s1.Item1 == s2.Item1)
        // Xs are equal, handle this case as you like
    else
        // calculate the interpolated point and put it in your output
}
```

I've shown this using an array list, but you can do it just as efficiently with a linked list; just use a "current" pointer to track your position in series2 instead of an index.

The complexity here is O(m + n), as you traverse both lists once each (in the worst and [most likely] average cases). The best case is O(n), but this will only happen in degenerate instances (all series1 X values are larger than the smallest series2 X value, or series2 is empty). Remember that this requires both lists to be sorted, so you're looking at O(m + n + m log m + n log n) all told. Note that this complexity is dominated by the sorting costs, meaning it's quite efficient.